# Using sed to delete all lines between two matching patterns

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file something like:

```
# ID 1
blah blah
blah blah
$ description 1
blah blah
# ID 2
blah
$ description 2
blah blah
blah blah
```

How can I use a sed command to delete all lines between the `#` and `$` line? So the result will become:

```
# ID 1
$ description 1
blah blah
# ID 2
$ description 2
blah blah
blah blah
```

Can you please kindly give an explanation as well?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Use this sed command to achieve that:

```
sed '/^#/,/^\$/{/^#/!{/^\$/!d}}' file.txt
```

Mac users (to prevent `extra characters at the end of d command` error) need to add semicolons before the closing brackets

```
sed '/^#/,/^\$/{/^#/!{/^\$/!d;};}' file.txt
```

#### OUTPUT

```
# ID 1
$ description 1
blah blah
# ID 2
$ description 2
blah blah
blah blah
```

#### Explanation:

- `/^#/,/^\$/` will match all the text between lines starting with `#` to lines starting with `$`. `^` is used for start of line character. `$` is a special character so needs to be escaped.
- `/^#/!` means do following if start of line is not `#`
- `/^$/!` means do following if start of line is not `$`
- `d` means delete

So overall it is first matching all the lines from `^#` to `^\$` then from those matched lines finding lines that **don't match** `^#` and **don't match** `^\$` and deleting them using `d`.

Comment: For Mac users: To prevent `extra characters at the end of d command` error you need to add semicolons before the closing brackets `sed '/^#/,/^\$/{/^#/!{/^\$/!d;};}' file.txt`

Comment: How would you do that if you want to include the # and $ lines for deletion? If you want to find $ at the end of a line, you can do $\$,

Comment: Then just use: `sed '/^#/,/^\$/d' file`

Comment: I used `sed '/^====/,/^>>>>/d' file-with-git-merge-conflicts.xml > file-ok.xml` to remove git merge conflict lines between '=======' and '>>>>>>> branch-name, and `sed '/^<<<</d'` to remove '<<<<<<< HEAD' lines (my real file was a Dia software file), but mergetool like meld should be useful !-)

Answer (score 64):

```
$ cat test
1
start
2
end
3
$ sed -n '1,/start/p;/end/,$p' test
1
start
end
3
$ sed '/start/,/end/d' test
1
3
```

Comment: The speed at which this works on 300mb files is impressive. I'm talking split second on a SSD.

Comment: I was a little confused since I'm not familiar with the sed syntax.  It was not clear that the first and second sed commands did not have a dependency - i.e. the difference between the two is whether you want to preserve the match token or not.  Until I tested it, I had assumed the first command removed everything between the tokens and the second removed the tokens themselves.  If you're trying to strip out a chunk between tokens you only need to use the second command.

Comment: No idea why, but `'1,/start/p;/end/,$p'` completely screwed up my workflow, as I was relying on this working. It does not work at all for me.

Comment: https://github.com/theAkito/akito-libbash/blob/dd91364083f13d1132d68489172bbce664b9c9c0/setup.bash#L37 is the line in question. Did I miss something? Because to me it looks like it is exactly as you have shown in your answer @Lri.

Comment: The solution that actually works is the following: `sed '/PATTERN-1/,/PATTERN-2/{//!d}' input.txt`

Comment: Thank you @Akito this works for me too in Fish shell

Answer (score 29):

In general form, if you have a file with contents of form *abcde*, where section *a* precedes pattern *b*, then section *c* precedes pattern *d*, then section *e* follows, and you apply the following `sed` commands, you get the following results.

In this demonstration, the output is represented by `=> abcde`, where the letters show which sections would be in the output. Thus, `ae` shows an output of only sections *a* and *e*, `ace` would be sections *a*, *c*, and *e*, etc.

Note that if `b` or `d` appear in the output, those are the patterns appearing (i.e., they're treated as if they're sections in the output).

Also don't confuse the `/d/` pattern with the command `d`. The command is always at the end in these demonstrations. The pattern is always between the `//`.

- `sed -n -e '/b/,/d/!p' abcde` => ae
- `sed -n -e '/b/,/d/p' abcde` => bcd
- `sed -n -e '/b/,/d/{//!p}' abcde` => c
- `sed -n -e '/b/,/d/{//p}' abcde` => bd
- `sed -e '/b/,/d/!d' abcde` => bcd
- `sed -e '/b/,/d/d' abcde` => ae
- `sed -e '/b/,/d/{//!d}' abcde` => abde
- `sed -e '/b/,/d/{//d}' abcde` => ace

Comment: Is there any way to get `ade`?

Answer (score 23):

Another approach with sed:

```
sed '/^#/,/^\$/{//!d;};' file
```

- `/^#/,/^\$/`: from line starting with `#` up to next line starting with `$`
- `//!d`: delete all lines except those matching the address patterns

Comment: how do you do this inclusive of the patterns?

Comment: Try this: `sed '/^#/,/^\$/d;' file`.

Comment: How to delete including only the first or only the last pattern?

Answer (score 7):

I did something like this long time ago and it was something like:

```
sed -n -e "1,/# ID 1/ p" -e "/\$ description 1/,$ p"
```

Which is something like:

- `-n` suppress all output
- `-e "1,/# ID 1/ p"` execute from the first line until your pattern and p (print)
- `-e "/\$ description 1/,$ p"` execute from the second pattern until the end and p (print).

I might be wrong with some of the escaping on the strings, so please double check.

Answer (score -1):

The example below removes lines between ***"if"*** and ***"end if"***.

All files are scanned, and lines between the two matching patterns are removed ( including them ).

```
IFS='
'
PATTERN_1="^if"
PATTERN_2="end if"

# Search for the 1st pattern in all files under the current directory.
GREP_RESULTS=(`grep -nRi "$PATTERN_1" .`)

# Go through each result
for line in "${GREP_RESULTS[@]}"; do

   # Save the file and line number where the match was found.
   FILE=${line%%:*}
   START_LINE=`echo "$line" | cut -f2 -d:`

   # Search on the same file for a match of the 2nd pattern. The search 
   # starts from the line where the 1st pattern was matched.
   GREP_RESULT=(`tail -n +${START_LINE} $FILE | grep -in "$PATTERN_2" | head -n1`)
   END_LINE="$(( $START_LINE + `echo "$GREP_RESULT" | cut -f1 -d:` - 1 ))"

   # Remove lines between first and second match from file
   sed -e "${START_LINE},${END_LINE}d;" $FILE > $FILE

done
```

Comment: I would not recommend your approach.  While it demonstrates a couple of cool things like how to parse the output of grep in a clever way, your script runs several external programs and calls the shell functions several times when it can all be done internallly by sed, much more efficiently.  Thus the downvote.