# How do I filter out multiple lines which starts and ends with a given pattern?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, awk, sed, grep

In my company, we have a huge log file with java stacktraces. In general, its format is:

```
useful line 1
useful line 2
useful line 3
MARKER1 start of exception
... <--Around 100 lines here
end of exception MARKER2
useful line 4
useful line 5
useful line 6
MARKER1 start of exception
... <--Around 100 lines here
end of exception MARKER2
useful line 7
```

It has useful information mixed with useless exceptions.

Is it possible to filter out the entire contents of useless exceptions from the logs using a combination of awk/sed/grep..?

In the example above, the output would be:

```
useful line 1
useful line 2
useful line 3
useful line 4
useful line 5
useful line 6
useful line 7
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287755/using-sed-to-delete-all-lines-between-two-matching-patterns

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14492880/2038383

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus, I added sample input and output to my original post.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns

Comment: @user674669: Your example ist useless. `grep "useful line" file`

Answer (score 3):

#### Using awk

To exclude the start and end of exceptions and everything in between:

```
$ awk '/start of exception/,/end of exception/{next} 1' file
useful line 1
useful line 2
useful line 3
useful line 4
useful line 5
useful line 6
useful line 7
```

How it works:

- `/start of exception/,/end of exception/{next}`

  For any line in the range from the start to the end of the exception, we skip the rest of the commands and start over on the `next` line.
- `1`

  For any other lines, we print them.  `1` is awk's shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Using sed

```
$ sed '/start of exception/,/end of exception/d' file
useful line 1
useful line 2
useful line 3
useful line 4
useful line 5
useful line 6
useful line 7
```

How it works:

- `/start of exception/,/end of exception/d`

  For any line in the range from the start to the end of the exception, we delete the line (`d`).

All other lines are, by default, printed.

Answer (score 3):

another `sed` with anchored patterns

```
$ sed '/^MARKER1/,/MARKER2$/d' file

useful line 1
useful line 2
useful line 3
useful line 4
useful line 5
useful line 6
useful line 7
```

or translated to `awk`

```
$ awk '/^MARKER1/,/MARKER2$/{next} 1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your input, you can do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ flag=1 } /MARKER/ {flag=!flag; next} flag' file
useful line 1
useful line 2
useful line 3
useful line 4
useful line 5
useful line 6
useful line 7
```

As pointed out in comments, you can also do:

```
awk '/MARKER/{f=!f;next} !f' file
```

Comment: perhaps shorter with `awk '/MARKER/{f=!f;next} !f'`

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
cat filename | grep useful
```

will work

Comment: `grep useful filename` will work for the given example. The actual logfile might have other text, like starting with a timestamp for every useful line.
In that case you can change your command into `grep "^2" logfile` of `grep -E " ERROR| WARN| INFO" logfile` when these lines are useful.