# How do I delete everything until the end of a file after a pattern using sed?

Tags: linux, sed

I want to change this:

```
--- BEGINNING OF file.txt ---
# use another authentication method.

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all
--- END ---
```

... to this:

```
--- BEGINNING OF file.txt ---
# use another authentication method.

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
--- END ---
```

Here's my latest attempt ("-i" to be added):

`sed "s/^\(.*type\s*database\s*user\s*address\s*method\).*$/\1/i" file.txt`

Thank you!

Comment: it's not what you search ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287755/using-sed-to-delete-all-lines-between-two-matching-patterns

Comment: I tried sed '/.*type\s*database\s*user\s*address\s*method\$/!d' pg_hba.conf, though that post's answer was too cryptic for me.  Thanks, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `s` command is, indeed sed's Swiss Army knife, but when you want to delete entire lines, it's the wrong tool. You want the `d` command:

```sh
sed '0,/type\s\+database\s\+user\s\+address\s\+method/I!d'
```

The address `0,/.../I` matches all lines from the beginning of the file (`0`) to the first line that matches the regular expression, case insensitive (`I`—available in GNU sed but not POSIX sed). `!` inverts the match so `d` deletes the lines that *don't* match. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3NDoIwEITvPMUKR434CjWQ6MFo@DmYeFnbGhpL17AlkafHAhd1LjObzHzLWo3jbpP64aVvfFsr9HhHnnPPupscleo08xRb7RtS6XEVVgmEAqAj3@gOsA/mvJHoDTlYitsoSqC6XnKATFRiL8qQFtVlXsCXRJYVeVnCv055dThnEye2JNHGYBge1EHtzBsUtWgcMMmn9iDJOS2n/wzk7BDNiwBBa3@g4f4A)

Comment: This was perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: @wmeitzen I've updated my answer to use `!d` instead of `p`, which makes the `-n` option unnecessary.

Comment: GNU sed only that. POSIX sed does not have `I`

Comment: @dawg Good catch. I'll edit my answer to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

This is also easily done with `awk`:

```
$ awk -v f=1 'f 
              {s=tolower($0)}
              s~/type\s+database\s+user\s+address\s+method/{f=!f}' file
```

Or,

```
 $ awk 'BEGIN{f=1}
        f 
        {s=tolower($0)}
         s~/type\s+database\s+user\s+address\s+method/{exit}' file
```

Outline:

```
 BEGIN{f=1}         # set a flag to true value
 f                  # print if that flag is true
 {s=tolower($0)}    # make the line lowercase
 s~/regex/{exit}    # at the regex but after printing -- exit
```

Which can be further simplified to:

```
$ awk '1 
       tolower($0)~/type\s+database\s+user\s+address\s+method/{exit}' file
```