# delete rows after specific character | awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I am writing a Bash script and,
I need to remove all lines in between TER, including 'TER's

Input File :

```
ATOM    186  O3'   U     6       7.297   6.145  -5.250  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM    187 HO3'   U     6       7.342   5.410  -5.865  1.00  0.00           H  
TER
ATOM      1 HO5'   A     1       3.429  -7.861   3.641  1.00  0.00           H  
ATOM      2  O5'   A     1       4.232  -7.360   3.480  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM      3  C5'   A     1       5.480  -8.064   3.350  1.00  0.00           C  
ATOM      4  H5'   A     1       5.429  -8.766   2.518  1.00  0.00           H  
TER
```

Expected output:

```
ATOM    186  O3'   U     6       7.297   6.145  -5.250  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM    187 HO3'   U     6       7.342   5.410  -5.865  1.00  0.00           H
```

I found

```
sed '/TER/,$d' ${myArray[j]}.txt >> ${MyArray[j]}.txt  ### ${MyArray[j]} file name through an array
```

But this does not work, I think awk will work with Bash Script. help Thanks

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: same file no change

Comment: Appending to the same file you're reading is not the best idea.

Comment: expeced output is first two line, without line between TER ...... TER

Comment: The `sed` script `'/TER/,$d` by itself generates the correct output (even though it would delete also the lines following the second `TER`). But as @Shawn suggested, the problem in you original command is another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sed to delete all lines between two matching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287755/using-sed-to-delete-all-lines-between-two-matching-patterns)

Comment: @shawn you are right, changing the file name solved the problem, also append, only ">" I should use,
I would do it like this ${myArray[j]}.txt >> a.txt , in next command,
mv a.txt > ${myArray[j]}.txt
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done like this

```
sed '/TER/,$d' ${myArray[j]}.txt > tmp.txt #note only one " > "
mv tmp.txt ${myArray[j]}.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `sed` like this:

```
sed -i.bak '/^TER/,/^TER/d' "${myArray[j]}.txt"
cat "${myArray[j]}.txt"
```

```
ATOM    186  O3'   U     6       7.297   6.145  -5.250  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM    187 HO3'   U     6       7.342   5.410  -5.865  1.00  0.00           H
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed '/TER/,/TER/d'
```

```
   echo 
   "ATOM    186  O3'   U     6       7.297   6.145  -5.250  1.00  0.00           O  
    ATOM    187 HO3'   U     6       7.342   5.410  -5.865  1.00  0.00           H  
    TER
    ATOM      1 HO5'   A     1       3.429  -7.861   3.641  1.00  0.00           H  
    ATOM      2  O5'   A     1       4.232  -7.360   3.480  1.00  0.00           O  
    ATOM      3  C5'   A     1       5.480  -8.064   3.350  1.00  0.00           C  
    ATOM      4  H5'   A     1       5.429  -8.766   2.518  1.00  0.00           H  
    TER"  |sed '/TER/,/TER/d' 


######################################################################################

ATOM    186  O3'   U     6       7.297   6.145  -5.250  1.00  0.00           O  
ATOM    187 HO3'   U     6       7.342   5.410  -5.865  1.00  0.00           H
```

```
sed '/Start Pattern/,/End Pattern/d'
```

Comment: Better anchored as `sed '/^\s*TER$/,/^\s*TER$/d'` to require `TER` as the first non-whitespace word and disambiguating from `TERMINAL`, etc..

Answer (score 0):

`awk` also provides a simple solution using a flag to control printing. Below the `skip` variable is used as a flag. If `1` the lines are skipped, on the transition from `1` to `0`, the script exits.

```
awk -v skip=0 '$1=="TER"{skip=skip?1:0; if (!skip)exit}1' file
```

Above `$1=="TER"` is used to match lines (records) where the first field is `TER` (this disambiguates between `"TER"` and `"TERMINAL"`, etc...) Within the rule, the ternary `skip=skip?1:0` sets `skip=1` the first time `"TER"` is encountered and to `0` on the next. If `skip==0` the script exits. The `1` at the end is just shorthand for `print`.

**Example Use/Output**

Using your data in `file`, you would get:

```
$ awk -v skip=0 '$1=="TER"{skip=skip?1:0; if (!skip)exit}1' file
ATOM    186  O3'   U     6       7.297   6.145  -5.250  1.00  0.00           O
ATOM    187 HO3'   U     6       7.342   5.410  -5.865  1.00  0.00           H
```