# I am looking for a sed command, to reduce multi-line comments in source code to single line

Tags: sed

I am looking for a sed command to join all comments in source file after a **Startmarker:** and before **endMarker** (excluding)
into a single line. There may possibly be a blank line before the endmarker or not.

```
    Startmarker: comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here 
    comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here.
    endMarker code
    code
code
code
     Startmarker: comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here 
    comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here.
    endMarker

code 
code
```

I have tried the following

```
awk '
  /.*Startmarker/,/.*endMarker/ {

    if (/\n/)                   
      printf "%s", $0          
    else
      print
  }
' file.name
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have given example of where i am .

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sed to delete all lines between two matching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287755/using-sed-to-delete-all-lines-between-two-matching-patterns)

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try the following:

```
awk '
/Startmarker/ {
    comment = $0        # assign the variable "comment" to the line
    f = 1               # set flag to indicate now in the comment context
    next                # skip the following codes
}
/endMarker/ {
    if (/^[[:blank:]]*endMarker[[:blank:]]*$/) {
                        # the line contains the "endMarker" keyword only
        print comment
    } else {
        sub(/endMarker/, "\n")
                        # the line contains the "endMarker" keyword and others
        print comment $0
    }
    f = 0               # reset the flag
    next
}
f {
    comment = comment $0
                        # append the line to the variable "comment"
    next
}
1                       # synonym to "print"
' file
```

Output with the provided example:

```
    Startmarker: comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here     comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here.
 code
    code
code
code
     Startmarker: comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here     comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here comments here.

code
code
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you tshiono. I will try this and revert.

Answer (score 0):

With `awk` set a flag when the `Startmarker` is found:

```
awk '/Startmarker/ {nonewline=1}
     /endMarker/ {nonewline=0} 
     { if (nonewline==1) printf("%s",$0); else print $0; }' file.name
```

Comment: Thank you Walter A. I will try this and revert.