# Removing delimited block of code between patterns using bash (regex, sed)

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file with `visibility` declarations, spanning over one or more lines, that I want removed *only* if they are in a `test` block.

i.e. input.txt:

```
test(
    srcs = [
        "test1",
    ],
    visibility = [
        "common",
    ],
    deps = [ "deps" ],
)

test(
    srcs = [
        "test2",
    ],
    visibility = [ "common" ],
)
```

i.e. output:

```
test(
    srcs = [
        "test1",
    ],
    deps = [ "deps" ],
)

test(
    srcs = [
        "test2",
    ],
)
```

---

The visibility lines could be inside other blocks i.e. `etc(...)`, in which case they should not be removed. i.e.:

```
etc(
    src = [
        "etc",
    ],
    # should not be removed because it's not inside a test(...) block
    visibility = [
        "common",
    ],
)
```

This is what I have tried, however, this only matches `visibility` blocks spanning over a  single line:

```
#!/bin/bash
#remove_lines.sh
remove_visibility_lines () {
    start_pattern="test"
    end_pattern=")"

    pattern_to_remove="visibility = \[.*\],"

    sed "/${start_pattern}/,/${end_pattern}/{/${pattern_to_remove}/d}" "$1"
}

remove_visibility_lines $1
```

`$ ./remove_lines.sh input.txt`

I've tried several ways to get this to remove visibility spanning over multiple block, i.e. `(.*?)` and `(\_.*)`, but I can't seem to get it to work.
Please help?

*Question is similar to:
[Using sed to delete all lines between two matching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287755/using-sed-to-delete-all-lines-between-two-matching-patterns/6287940) , however, in my case I have patterns nested inside patterns. I.e.: you only look inside the `test(...)` block, and only inside those blocks you remove the `visibility = [...],` blocks.*

Comment: `(.*?)` is undefined behavior in sed and awk, I suspect it probably means something in perl but idk. Please google BREs (as used by default in all sed variants), EREs (awk and GNU or BSD sed), and PCREs (perl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`, assuming no nested `()` characters:

```sh
awk '/^test\(/{f=1} $0==")"{f=0}
     f && /visibility = \[/{v=1} !v; /],/{v=0}' ip.txt
```

- `/^test\(/{f=1}` set flag `f` if a line starts with `test(`
- `$0==")"{f=0}` clear flag `f` if a line contains `)` only
- `f && /visibility = \[/{v=1}` set flag `v` if `f` is also set and a line contains `visibility = [`
- `!v;` to print input lines only if flag `v` is not set
- `/],/{v=0}` clear flag `v` if line contains `],`

To pass start and end strings:

```sh
$ cat script.awk
index($0, start) == 1 { f = 1 }
$0 == end { f = 0 }
f && /visibility = \[/ { v = 1 }
! v { print }
/],/ { v = 0 }

$ awk -v start='test(' -v end=')' -f script.awk ip.txt
```