# sed to delete lines between two matching patterns

Tags: linux, awk, sed

Using sed, I'm looking to delete the lines between two words (or pattern) `revolving_door_cad` to the next appereance of that word `revolving_door_cad`, 2nd pattern should be excluded. I tried something like `sed '/revolving_door_cad/,/revolving_door_cad/{//!d;}' file` but its removing both the sections.

cat file.json

```
.....
.....

'revolving_door_cad': {
   'id': 'as-hp-pass-files',
   'labels': {
        'name': 'jonah',
        'type': 'File',
        'Eligible': 'true',
        'Applied': 'ransomware'
         },
         'data': {
           'file.pcx': 'home/work/300029_LATAM/PROD-AS-ransomware/account',
        },
      },
'revolving_door_cad': {
  ....
  ....
```

Output should look like

```
'revolving_door_cad': {
  ....
  ....
```

Comment: Does [Using `sed` to delete all lines between two matching patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6287755/) answer your question?

Comment: @U880D : SOrry no, I tried `sed '/revolving_door_cad/,/revolving_door_cad/{//p;d;}' file` it results in ` 'revolving_door_cad': {
  'revolving_door_cad': { .....`

Comment: I'm looking to delete the 1st `revolving_door_cad` as well

Comment: Since the input looks like JSON, wouldn't an other tool like `jq` be a better choice?

Comment: If this is supposed to be JSON, it's broken. (Proper JSON uses double quotes around strings.)

Comment: Actually its jsonnet files