# Delete bash history in Centos 6.2

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I accidentally copied a huge block of text into my Centos6.2 shell and it's annoying me in my bash history, how can I delete it?

I tried to run `history -d {{ number }}` but it comes back the next time I open a shell :(

Additionally when I tried using `history -d $i` in a for i in list loop 
, I don't think it deleted anything as they run in subshells .

Comment: What about `rm ~/.bash_history`?

Comment: do you wanna get rid of all history commands ?

Comment: All will be fine but am curious to know if can be done for any specific dates or time?

Comment: Use: [`vim ~/.bash_history`](https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=10152204120002323&set=a.10150339989232323.397391.628937322) to [selectively delete lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362363/vim-how-to-delete-a-large-block-of-text-without-counting-the-lines) you don't want...

Comment: Also, if you happen to copy-paste a chunk of lines on terminal (this itself is a security risk, but anyway, you have already done that error...) & you don't want the history to be written to file, set [`HISTFILE=/dev/null`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-History-Facilities.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following command to clean the .bash_history file:

```
history -w 
history -c
```

And to delete a particular line, use following:

```
history -d <line_number> // deletes the line from history in memory
```

`history -w` will write the current in-memory changes to .bash_history file.

Comment: Thanks Worked Perfectly