# osx: vim visual cut and paste leaves whitespace, overwrites

Tags: macos, vim

(Note: not off topic per [Is it appropriate to post vim questions on Stack Overflow now that there is a vi/vim site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287089/is-it-appropriate-to-post-vim-questions-on-stack-overflow-now-that-there-is-a-vi))

On my mac using vim version:

`VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jun 10 2016 10:50:34) MacOS X (unix) version Included patches: 1-1219`

when I am in visual mode, select a block of text, then click `x`, the text is removed but the whitespace remains. Here is a video: https://vimeo.com/176318393

similarly, when I paste using `"+p` (pastes from the system clipboard), the text overwrites whatever is on those lines and does not "bump" down the text being pasted. Video: https://vimeo.com/176319290

I want to solve these two problems but I have a hunch they are related so I am posting them in one question here.

A subset of my vimrc (vimrc is massive but nearly positive the plugin stuff has nothing that could affect this) that handles generic settings is here: http://pastebin.com/2APD1ycp

What is wrong?

Comment: Would have been more appropriate on the Vi site...

Comment: @Mat I see no difference between my question and the question you answered here, because neither are about programming and both are very generic vim usage questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362363/vim-how-to-delete-a-large-block-of-text-without-counting-the-lines. If my question is off topic here "now" then posts like that should be migrated.

Comment: Look at the date. Also, lacking details. Please post your settings also.

Comment: @Mat vimrc link added.

Comment: First problem doesn't seem to exist for me. Did you tried starting vim like `vim -u NONE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior shown in both videos is perfectly normal and expected in visual block mode.

You have *visual mode* and *visual line mode* at your disposal so, if you don't want the behavior of visual block mode… don't use it.